# Avoid multiple import of the same packages in several python modules

Tags: python, import, package, init, python-module

I'm designing a Python package with this structure :

```
package
 |_subpackage1
     |_module11.py
     |_module12.py
     |___init__.py
 |_subpackage2
     |_module21.py
     |_module22.py 
     |___init__.py
 |___init__.py
```

All modules require common external packages like `numpy` or `os`, and call each other: 
for instance `module11` calls `module21` and `module11` calls `module21`

So far, all my module have a very long import header, to import the external packages and my own modules. I remarked that when I call my module with Ananconda, my scripts are very slow to initialize, and I presume it is because of those complex inter-connected imports

What should I put in the different `__init__.py` to avoid multiple imports of the same package, and long header in each module, both for the external packages and my own modules ?

Comment: Could you include one of your `__init__.py` files please?

Comment: so far, they are empty

Comment: i have same issues. @covich, have you found any solutions on this please?